# HTML is not getting data from SQLdatabase

Tags: php, android, mysql, cordova

I m using Phonegap for my project which find the current location, passes latitude and longitude to php script, and php searches the sql database if it has any place/institute nearby to current location. i Get the output using xampp,it returns me the institute name on html screen. But when i use the apk file and run the same code in my phone i just get the current lat/lon coord but doesnt get the institude name.
Here is My geolocation.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
    var lat;
    var lon;

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');

        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude          + '<br />' +    
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
        lat= position.coords.latitude;
        lon= position.coords.longitude;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon,true)
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="t01"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is radius.php code. uploaded in 000webhost.com

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "****";
$mysql_database = "****";
$mysql_user = "****";
$mysql_password = "****";
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$rad = 7.442;  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers
$R = 6371;  // earth's mean radius, km
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lon = $_GET['lon'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, ClassName,City, latitude, longitude, ( 6371 * acos(   cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('$lon') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM geodata HAVING distance < '$rad' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $row['ID'] . " " . $row['ClassName'];
    echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My database has been uploaded on 000webhost with coreect password,webhost,user and database name.Please help me. Please see The Code is working in Xampp.but not working on my android phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off-  why are you bothering writing XHR code that is compatible with IE6? You don't need to worry about IE6 on a mobile device. That being said, have you modified the  tag in your config.xml? Details here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: i copy pasted the code was lazy enough to delete IE^ compatible code :p. also can u please say me which link i have to write in access origin? same as given in ur link ? i am a newbie. ty for instant reply

Comment: ty so much @Raymond Camden. i didnt modified my config.xml, now everthing working awesome :). for others who got this problem i had to add the below line in config.xml <access  origin="website where uploaded php file"/>

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap cannot contain package PHP. You can interact with your database with other methods, you could use javascript to pass the data in an Ajax call to a PHP page that deals with responses. (just an example way of doing this).

But to answer your question you can't package PHP in phonegap.

Comment: i have did the same. i havent included php in phonegap. php code is uploaded in 000webhost. and i have used get method of ajax to interact with php. ty for reply :)